# Terraform, Kubernetes and Helm – Setting Up CI for Deployments

Tags: docker, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I currently have a cluster spun up by terraform, where I don't have kubeconfig generated, but I do have the info I need to pass a kubernetes block in.

```
provider "kubernetes" {  
load_config_file       = false
host                   = local.kubernetes_config.host
cluster_ca_certificate = local.kubernetes_config.cluster_ca_certificate
token                  = local.kubernetes_config.token
}
```

via terraform, I can use the helm integration to install helm packages easily.

- I want to setup a CI pipeline to do helm upgrade
- I do not have a kube-config, but I have the host, cluster_ca_certificate and token.
- **How should I setup helm upgrades from my CI server?**

I think this is a pretty common usecase, but I can't figure out how to integrate helm and my CI server, since terraform doesn't give me a `kubeconfig` I can pass through my system, only the `host`, `cluster_ca_certificate` and `token`.

I tried working with the `helm --token` integration, but this strategy didn't work for me.

Comment: You haven't specified whether `token` is the **join** token, or the `ServiceAccount` token; in general the question seems like it's off to a bad start with "I don't have a kubeconfig but I want to do kubernetes things." It **for sure** is not a "common usecase" to say "I don't have keys to my car but I want to drive to the grocery store"

Comment: @mdaniel how would you get a kubeconfig for a cluster you provision within terraform?  would you shell out using `local-exec` to `gcloud` inside the terraform?  something else?

Comment: I pulled the token from the cluster in terraform.  works great to provision other things via terraform file:
https://gist.github.com/kenmazaika/638cfc4ed9cd008f001928a5d9b735d5

Comment: If it "works great" then what's your question, because as written it sounds as if you don't have a working kubeconfig but are surprised that things which require kubeconfig are upset

Comment: works great to connect to kubernetes within terraform.  does not work when using the helm command line outside terraform within a CI environment.  how would you get a kubeconfig for a cluster you provision within terraform?

Comment: In this setup, I'd make sure my Helm chart takes an image tag as a value, pass that into the Terraform resource, and configure that using a Terraform variable.  I've generally seen Terraform used a little more for infrastructure and a little less for deploying application code, though: I think it's more common to use Helm directly in this setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks so much for the feedback.  I was just starting to consider using terraform for the upgrade but was wondering if that was common or if using helm directly would make more sense.  My gut tells me I should use helm directly, like you suggest.  I think I almost have a solution using `gcloud`, when I do I'm planning to post the answer here.